# Can "Curve Fitting" be seen as an Alternative to Numerical Differentiation?

Tags: regression, curve-fitting, kernel-smoothing, splines, interpolation

For a long time, the following point always confused me: **If the "Fundamental Theorem of Calculus" tells us that all real and continuous functions are differentiable (i.e. have derivatives) - then why do we need numerical differentiation?**

Then, I found out that numerical differentiation is used in instances when we do not have the actual equation of the "function", but instead only have observed data points from this "function" instead:

[image]

Thus, it seems as Numerical Differentiation is providing us with a way to "interpolate derivatives" at arbitrary points over an observed range. This leads me to my next point: it seems that there are many instances in statistics where we are faced with a very similar problem : for example, we are often given a set of data points and are sometimes interested in interpolation, or fitting a smoothed function through these points:

[image]

As far as I know, this can be done in many different ways, such as:

- **Polynomial Regression**
- **(Smoothed) Splines**
- **(Smoothed) Kernel Density Estimation**

By fitting a smoothed function to the data (as opposed to a piecewise function), this allows us to obtain an "analytical and closed form" function that passes through the data (we can also measure the quality of how well this function fits the data) - and then we should be able to differentiate (i.e. evaluate derivatives) this function at any point that we desire.

For instance, provided if we have sufficient reasons to believe that the regression models below fit the data well - could we not just evaluate derivatives (e.g. first derivative, second derivative) of these regression models and use them as surrogates for numerical differentiation?

[image]

**My Question:** **Is fitting a statistical model a mathematically valid alternative to numerical differentiation?**  The only downside to this I can think of is that this approach requires you to first fit a statistical model to the observed data (a source of error and uncertainty) and then differentiate this fitted statistical model (another source of error and uncertainty) - effectively compounding the uncertainties through error propagation. I am not sure, but perhaps standard numerical differentiation techniques (e.g. Backwards Differencing, Forward Differencing ) have less of a chance of invoking such error prorogation.

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

Comment: It is absolutely possible for a continuous function to be non-differentiable, there are continuous functions that a *nowhere* differentiable. Awful monstrous things. More on topic, it's possible for a sequence of (smooth( functions $f_i$ to converge to some limiting function $g_i$, but the derivatives $f'_i$ do not converge to $g'$, you can set it up so that the derivatives don't converge at all (think of adding more and more small amplitude oscillations to the $f_i$, so the derivatives get larger and larger). Theres no guarantee that an approximation of a function approximates the derivative.

Comment: @ Matthew drury: yes, i agree! The Weistrass function is not double diffrentiable, even though it is continuous!

Comment: (+1 to Matthew's comment) To comment further: Finite precision. Using numerical derivatives is actually quite computationally expensive and not so accurate as one might initially expect. Case in point: Numerical optimisation. If it was so easy to get derivatives we would use Newton's method pretty much everywhere; reality is that we try to use it pretty much everywhere (cause it is really fast) but we can't get it to work so... (insert myriads of algorithms: from quasi-Newton ones to derivative free, to literally random sampling).

Comment: Questions that are predicated on obviously false statements (such as "all ... continuous functions are differentiable") tend not to be received well, because it becomes impossible to determine how to respond to them: correct the false assumptions or attempt to interpret the question absent such assumptions and answer that?

Comment: Incidentally, there is a clear distinction between most applications of numerical differentiation and "interpolating derivatives:" in the former case, one can compute values of the function at arbitrary points.  In the latter case, values of the *derivative* would be given at a *fixed* set of points.  There's not much of a relationship between the two settings.